# Как в питоне объединить 2 массива в один?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в этом примере объединить эти два массива в один?

```
from array import *
f = array('i', [1, 3, 5, 6, 0])
c = array('i', [0, 2, 4, 7, 9])
```

Вывод:
`[1, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0, 2, 4, 7, 9]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я что-то не понимаю, или ответ ниже?:-)

```
from array import *
f = array('i', [1, 3, 5, 6, 0])
c = array('i', [0, 2, 4, 7, 9])

print (list (f+c)) # [1, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0, 2, 4, 7, 9]
```

Comment: А возможен ли вывод без i?

Comment: @SansReqret `i` обозначает тип массива - `signed int`

Comment: Возможен, исправил. Теперь совсем, как в вопросе вывод. Но вообще тут "+" между массивами надо было автоматически поставить, и посмотреть, что получится. Аналогично, увидев [] можно list писать автоматически. У Python операции достаточно типизированы.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Благодарю за пояснение

Comment: @Сергей То есть всё было проще и можно было преобразовать массив в список, большое спасибо за ответ

Comment: @SansReqret, более того, как пишу выше, квадратные скобки просто требовали преобразовать, явно указывая тип.

Answer (score 3):

использовать распаковку

```
[*f, *c]
```